# Rename multiple files in a cycle

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to rename files in an exact folder.
I have a set:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
...
n.png.
```

I need to change names so the each name becomes i+1 like:

```
2.png
3.png
...
n+1.png
```

The code is:

```
var1=1 
for file in *.png
do
    mv "$file" "${file/((var1+1))/1}"
    ((i += 1))
done
```

I know, that there is a global problem, but can't understand how to correct it.

Comment: how many such files are there.. because we can work out from the largest number

Answer (score 1):

Do it the reverse way, or you'll lose all files, except `1.png`, which is renamed to `n+1.png`

```sh
for n in $(seq n -1 1)
do
    mv "$n.png" "$((n + 1)).png"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way using the Perl one-liner. The one-liner automatically gets the highest number and loops to print the mv statements. And you have to pipe it to shell like `| ksh` to rename the file.

```
$ ls -1 *png
1.png
2.png
3.png
4.png
$ perl -ne ' BEGIN { @f= reverse sort(@ARGV) ; foreach my $x (@f) { $nf=$x;$nf=~s/(\d+)/eval($1+1)/ge; print "mv $x $nf\n" } } ' *.png
mv 4.png 5.png
mv 3.png 4.png
mv 2.png 3.png
mv 1.png 2.png
$
```